# how to set node.js as a service on a private server?[can't access the node application]

Tags: node.js, centos, ip-address, production-environment, server-configuration

I have a problem when deploying my node.js on a private server. I just can't access it when i type the ip:5000 in the browser. This is what netstat shows:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
126.0.54.248    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         126.0.54.249    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
```

And this is my node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

var port = 5000;
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, function(err) {
    console.log(err, server.address()); // prints undefined { address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 5000 }  
});
```

I also added the ip address in my hosts file. What am I doing wrong that I can not access the webserver?(Yes I have the node server running)

Comment: Maybe the server is not allowing connections to port 5000. Try a well known port number like 80 or 8080 first. If you can't connect I suggest you to check if you can connect to other ports that you know the server is listening and also you should check how to allow connections to ports

Comment: Try `curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/` locally on the server, if it works, then your server is not allowing connections to port 5000 from outside and you'll have to manually allow connections.

Comment: thx....it really helped alot..it seems the server did not allow connections on that port